# Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript print widget with tile layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I am using the ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.24 print widget.

I am not able to print (pdf, png, etc) with a tile layer added as basemap. It is printing without tile layer, but not if tile layer is switched on. Below is the code.

Do you have any solution for me?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Print widget | Sample | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.24</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
 
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
 
        .esri-zoom {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
 
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
"esri/layers/TileLayer",
"esri/layers/support/TileInfo",
"esri/Basemap",
            "esri/widgets/LayerList",
            "esri/widgets/Print",
        ], (
            MapView,
            Map,
            FeatureLayer,
            MapImageLayer,
TileLayer,
TileInfo,
Basemap,
            LayerList,
            Print
        ) => {
baseLayer = new TileLayer({
url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer",
  id: "base",
  });
//baseLayer.maxScale = 0;
  basemap = new Basemap({
      baseLayers: [baseLayer ],    
      title:"base_map",
      id:"base_map"
    });
            const map = new Map({
           // basemap: "topo-vector",// basemap
basemap: basemap
            });
            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
//center: [0,0],
center: [-82.4645, 35.46453],
        constraints: {
rotationEnabled: false,
           lods: TileInfo.create({
             spatialReference: {
            wkid: 3857
           },
   numLODs: 10,
           }).lods
        },
zoom: 9,
            });
 
            const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer",
               // listMode: "hide"
            });
 
            const mapImageLayer = new MapImageLayer({
              url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer"   
            });
 
            map.add(featureLayer);
            //map.add(mapImageLayer);
try{
            view.when(() => {
                const print = new Print({
                    view: view,
                    printServiceUrl:
                        "https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task"
                });
 
                const layerList = new LayerList({
                    view: view
                });
 
                view.ui.add(print, "top-right");
                view.ui.add(layerList, "top-left");
            });
}
catch(e){
console.log("Error is " + e);
}
        });
 
    </script>
</head>
 
<body class="calcite">
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked if any of the known print limitations (see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-print.html) applies in your case?

Comment: in limitations of print widget, there is no mention of tile layer?

Comment: There are at least four points that talk about limitations regarding layers. Since you didn't include your code in the question, it's all just guessing on this side.

Comment: Without code for view creation and layers creation the above code does not help.

Comment: added code tried with MapServer url, but somewhat like this which is tiff published as tile layer, for print widget not showing this tif (tile layer)

Comment: Also, when added as MapImageLayer, it shows error as, message: "Unable to load image: https://.../MapServer/export"
name: "mapimagelayer:image-fetch-error" Is any export permission required?

Comment: I just checked Image Tile layer, its spatial reference is 3857 but published tile layer has spatial reference of 4326, does it make a difference?

I tried below url:

https://.../MapServer/export?bbox=(SPECIFY_BBOX_HERE_OF_3857)&bboxSR=3857&layers=&layerDefs=&size=&imageSR=4326&historicMoment=&format=gif&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&timeRelation=esriTimeRelationOverlaps&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&rotation=&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=.......

how & where to specify imageSR in print service for export? or bboxSR? if required

Answer (score 1):

Without event taking into consideration printing, you code above is total mess and can't work in any way.

First, your layer

```
baseLayer = new TileLayer({
  url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WindTurbines/MapServer/0",        
  id: "base",
});
```

is not a tile layer but an image layer, so it should look like this (and `url` without `0` at the end):

```
baseLayer = new MapImageLayer({
  url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WindTurbines/MapServer",        
  id: "base",
});
```

Second, your layer

```
const mapImageLayer = new MapImageLayer({
   url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer",
});
```

is not an image layer but tile layer and should look like this:

```
const mapImageLayer = new TileLayer({
   url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer",
});
```

After you take care of that, that's the map you get:

[image]

Reason for fuzzy image is that layer "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" has maximum native zoom 10.

Reason why you don't see turbines from base layer is that street map that is added later covers them. If you hide it, you now can see turbines:

[image]

Landscape trees layer `"https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0"` is on the other side of the USA near Ashville, so there is no way you can see it with restricted view extent. If you insert this code at the end:

```
view.when(() => {
  featureLayer.when(() => {
    const extent = Extent.fromJSON(featureLayer.sourceJSON.extent);
    view.goTo(extent);
  });
});
```

and hide streets layer that cover it, you'll see this:

[image]

After you sort this mess out and present some working code in a new question, we can start talking about printing.

Comment: it was an example to show ... i cannot find tile layer so added above layer from https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/ ... need to try tile layer as a Basemap and check print widget, i cannot share private url, need to try with public url or from sampleserver6  if it has tile layer

Comment: Also, I have edited above code & added World_Street_Map as basemap, but still print pdf shows empty, any reason or suggestions?

Comment: As I wrote, above code is a mess and you didn't change that. Ask a new question with a simple code that works without printing. After that we can talk about print problems.

Comment: As I said, I modified, just copy code run it, pdf shows empty